# Android - Crop circle facebook profile image

Tags: android, facebook, imageview, facebook-android-sdk

I am using `<com.facebook.widget.ProfilePictureView/>` and 
picture.setProfile(id) to load the image with facebook SDK.

i would like to now if there ir a way to apply a layer or something like that to crop the image as a circle.

Thanks!

Comment: There's no easy way to do this currently as the image view is not exposed from ProfilePictureView. You can potentially fork the SDK code from github for now, and expose the image view yourself.

Comment: You could use an overlay that matches the background color. But, if your background isn't just a color, that becomes troublesome. I use the profile image links directly and skip the widget. This allows controlling resolution, look, etc.